# How do I target this specific progress tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, progress-bar, progress

Im trying to create an audio preview page on my webpage where each audio element has its own progress bar. Im having trouble however, getting each audio element to target only its progress bar. I am pretty new to this, so I hope this isn't too much a straight forward dumb question, but I'd really appreciate the help, Thanks in advance.

This is the html for each song preview.

```
<audio id="player"></audio>

<div class="songPreview">
  <div class="disp">
    <div class="button" data-src="EXAMPLE.wav" data-pos="0">
      <a href="#" class="soundPlay"><img src="Buttons/play.png"></a>
      <a href="#" class="soundStop hidden"><img src="Buttons/stop.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="songInfo">
      <p>SONG NAME HERE</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <progress class="seekbar" value="0" max="1" style="width:250px"></progress>
</div>

<div class="songPreview2">
  <div class="disp">
    <div class="button" data-src="EXAMPLE2.wav" data-pos="0">
      <a href="#" class="soundPlay"><img src="Buttons/play.png"></a>
      <a href="#" class="soundStop hidden"><img src="Buttons/stop.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="songInfo">
      <p>SONG NAME HERE</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <progress class="seekbar" value="0" max="1" style="width:250px"></progress>
</div>
```

and this is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("player");
//play stop button etc.
    $(document).on('click', '.soundPlay', function(e) {
        var target = this;
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next("a").show();
        myAudio.src = target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-src');
        myAudio.play();
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.soundStop', function(e) {
        var target = this;
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev("a").show();
        $('audio').each(function(){
            this.pause();
            this.currentTime = 0;
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //end of play stop button

    //seekbar
    $('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
        $('.seekbar').attr("value", this.currentTime / this.duration);
    });
    //end seek bar

    //auto switch button on stop
    var audio = document.getElementById('player');
    audio.addEventListener('ended', stopAudio);

    function stopAudio() {
        audio.stop;
        $('.soundPlay').show('slow');
        $('.soundStop').hide('fast');
        $('.seekbar').attr(this.currentTime = 0);
    }
});
```

I just cant seem to figure out how to target only the progress tag in each respective div.
Is there anyway I can do this without a million different progress IDs and overly repetitive JS code?
( because there's gonna be like 100 of those song previews on a page )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see only one `audio` element. How are you assigning `src` to the `audio`. Post the whole JS code.

Comment: Your markup is somewhat confusing. You have one audio element #player, yet you have two divs each with a progress element. Can you clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, I updated the question with the entire JS code. 
Basically the audio tag is defined outside the divs and gets its data from the data-src in the button class.
However once any of the songs are playing, all the progress bars are moving, but i need to target only the one within the individual songPreview div. Thanks ShaunakD and @user3558931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to track the current sound `div` being played - with the `data-src`.

Use `.val()` instead of `attr('value')`

Try this,

```
$('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
    $('div[data-src="'+this.src+'"]').parents('.disp').siblings('.seekbar').val(this.currentTime / this.duration);
});
```

Also,

Change `stopAudio()` to this

```
function stopAudio() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    $('.soundPlay').show('slow');
    $('.soundStop').hide('fast');
    $('.seekbar').val(0);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ReeXf/1/)

Comment: Hmmm, no luck :(
Now the bars just wont move at all tho...
Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Still Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea, yours works in jsfiddle, but not in Dreamweaver. 
and no, no errors.
Also, in your Demo, both progress bars move instead of only one.

Ps. I really appreciate the time you're taking to try to help, Thanks so much.

Comment: Both work because I have specified same link for both. Check this. **http://jsfiddle.net/ReeXf/3/**. Are you getting any errors? Is the `progress` tag supported in your Dreamweaver? It is only supported in **HTML5** Have you used `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Comment: Ok I copied your code Exactly now, and it works : D. I realized the problem is, for some reason it doesn't work when I change the data-src to something like 

<div class="button" data-src="music/Maroon 5 - Doin' Dirt.wav" data-pos="0">

but it works with the example link you provided.

Comment: Please ignore the last comment. It works with the link types in your fiddle, even with the same file formats, just that for some reason the bars don't move when a local file is linked. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: The problem is the `src` attribute. You need to keep track of current sound being played in a global variable. Or have two audio tags

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks so much for your help, I'm finally getting somewhere :D